# How do you iterate backward over circular buffer without a conditional?

Tags: iteration, circular-buffer

Iterating forward through a circular buffer without using a conditional is easy with the remainder operator...

`iterator = (iterator + 1) % buffer_size;`

I can't for the life of me figure out the reverse operation, iterating backward.

Comment: it is not simply, `buffer_size - (iterator + 1) % buffer_size - 1`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does `iterator = (iterator + buffer_size - 1) % buffer_size` work for you? Go one less than all the way around.

Answer (score 0):

Borealid's answer works. (note: `iterator` is set to 0 initially).

Another solution is

`iterator = buffer_size - 1 - (buffer_size - iterator) % buffer_size` 
with `iterator` set to `buffer_size` initially.